# google maps integration details

Tags: google-maps, cakephp, integration

Does anyone know if it is possible to integrate Google maps and use also their data on topics.
Im using cakephp Framework.

I want to integrate a map of munich with fashion stores shown into my website.
But i want to show the results that come on google maps for fashion shops munich.
In the tutorials i see only ways to create your own markers.....

and second question is , i also would like to display the details , like opening hours and stuff.... is this data also available for automatic usage?

Comment: If you are looking for a PHP only solution: [GoogleMapV3Helper](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/) - You can retreive the geo data via the linked behavior and store it persistently in your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can style the POI on the map.

Also, you can only show the data google has available. They may not have every place, and a LOT of their places do not have hours. If you want a lot of data, I would suggest using your own markers.

Comment: tahts good. The thing is i want to generate this map for evry german city, so i depend on the data google has, because its too much to insert all of them on my own... but i might add own markers... wich is also possible right?   Do you have any further information how to add a google map wich shows allready the markers for munich fashion store for example?

Comment: Check out the google APIs for styling POI and for searching locations.